# How to show, then focus UISearchController programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I am using https://www.raywenderlich.com/4363809-uisearchcontroller-tutorial-getting-started as based project.

To make `UISearchController` hidden initially during app startup, I have move the following line of code, from `viewDidLoad` to `viewWillAppear`.

```
navigationItem.searchController = searchController
```

In order to start search feature, user will need to

1. "Pull down" `UITableView` to make `UISearchController` visible.
2. Tab on the `UISearchController`'s search bar so that the search bar is in focus.

Here's how it looks like

[image]

However, from UX point of view, user (Especially first time iPhone user) **cannot discover such search feature easily.**

We also do NOT want to display the search bar when the screen shows for the first time. **It occupies screen space**, and search feature is not a frequent accessed feature.

To make such search feature easy discoverable, we would like to provide a bar button item (with magnifying-glass icon) at top right. If user taps on it, the app will perform step 1 and step 2 programmatically.

May I know, how can I show, then focus UISearchController programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

You can try manually updating [`UISearchController.isActive`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchcontroller/1618659-isactive) to force launch the search interface.

> When the user taps in the search field of a managed search bar, the search controller automatically displays the search results controller. Usually, you get the value of this property to determine whether the search results are displayed. However, **you can set this property to `true` to force the search interface to appear, even if the user has not tapped in the search field**.
> The default value of this property is `false`.

Answer (score 1):

if I catch it correctly what did you say:

```
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.searchController.searchBar.searchTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
      }
      
    } else {
      // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
```